# how to send value as a parameter to loadURL() of electron main.js file from node js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

```
const electron = require("electron");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
const path = require("path");
​
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
​
  //window 1
  let win1 = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
  });
​
  win1.loadURL("https://twitter.com/");
  win1.on("closed", () => {
    win1 = null;
  });
}
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

i need to get url from frontend and access in node.js and pass to main.js loadURL() as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by this get url from frontend and access in node.js.
If my recognition is correct, I think you are going to read url from the renderer and send this to Electron main process to create BrowserWindow based on that url.
So communication between renderer and main.
Use this **ipcRenderer** and **ipcMain**.
You can send the url using **ipcRenderer** like this

```
...
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

    function sendUrlToMain(url) {
      ipcRenderer.sendSync('sendUrlToMain', url);
      return res;
    }
...
```

Then add this to main.js

```
ipcMain.on('sendUrlToMain',(event, arg) => {
let win1 = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
  });
​
  win1.loadURL(arg);
  win1.on("closed", () => {
    win1 = null;
  });
});
```

Comment: Electron combines the Chromium rendering engine and the Node.js runtime. So you can CRUD the file at main and send this to renderer. Electron itself is Node.js.